# Can't install python package Pybluez, showing "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required."

Tags: python, visual-c++, pybluez

I need to use Bluetooth in my Python program for some functionality. So I tried installing Pybluez, but I can't get it to go right no matter how I install it.
I used the following command to install it:

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git#egg=Pybluez
```

Then it told me to install MSVC 14.0+:

```
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      ......
      building 'bluetooth._msbt' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]
      ......
```

But I already have MSVC 14 installed on my system, and then I also tried to install the build tool from `https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=build%20tools%20for%20Visual%20Studio%202015%20update%203`.

[Installed MSVC tools.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy8JN.png)

So what should I do?

(My environment is Windows11, Python3.10)